# How is the expression below for a "one-body operator" obtained?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body

I don't understand the expression shown below (with text for context).
Is the operator $O$ assumed to be diagonal in the coordinate basis? Even if that
is the case, how does that give the sum $\sum_{i=1}^N O(\textbf{r}_i)$? Since
each coordinate is part of the product of coordinates space, I don't see how this 
is a sum rather than a product.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is the operator $O$ assumed to be diagonal in the coordinate basis?

The first line of the attached text explicitly states that $\hat{O}=\hat{O}(r)$, meaning that for a one-body wave function we would have
$$
\hat{O}|r\rangle = O(r) |r\rangle,
$$
where $O(r)$ is the eigenvalue of $\hat{O}$, and $\hat{}$ denotes the operator.

> Even if that is the case, how does that give the sum $\sum_{i=1}^N O(\textbf{r}_i)$?

Applying $\hat{O}$ on the N-body wavefunction of $|r_{1}, r_{2}, ...r_{N} \rangle$ would have the result of 
$$
\hat{O}|r_{1}, r_{2}, ...r_{N} \rangle= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} O(r_{i}) |r_{1}, r_{2}, ...r_{N} \rangle.
$$
Employing the orthoonormality of the wave-function, $\langle r'_{i} | r_{i} \rangle = \delta(r_{i}- r'_{i})$, would give us

$$
\begin{align}
\langle r'_{1}, r'_{2}, ...r'_{N} |
\hat{O}|r_{1}, r_{2}, ...r_{N} \rangle &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} O(r_{i}) \langle r'_{1}, r'_{2}, ...r'_{N} |r_{1}, r_{2}, ...r_{N} \rangle,\\
&= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} O(r_{i}) \prod_{j=1}^{N}\delta(r_{j}-r'_{j})
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you! Definitely helps me understand the statement. Could you clarify your second equation? Why does acting $O$ on the product state give a sum as the eigenvalue?

Comment: You should recall that in the one-body operator acts only on one one-body wavefunction. As the Fermionic or Bosonic many-body wavefunction consists N one-body wavefunctions, the eigenvalue of $\hat{O}$ on such state would be $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}O(r_{i})$.